# What is the best practice handle overlap gRPC dependencies in a CMake project?

Tags: cmake, build, grpc

Said I have a CMake project whose layout look like

```
MyProject
|- /src            : uses dep2-client and implements effective dep1-client
|- /contrib
   |- /dep1-proto  : contains proto defs dep1
   |- /dep2-proto  : contains proto defs dep2
   |- /dep2-client : depends on dep2-proto
```

Currently, I install gRPC system-wise and thus these projects live together well as when they really need gRPC dependencies, they first check `gRPC_FOUND` and if not try `find_library`.

However, I'd prefer not to install gRPC system-wise but as a third-party module. At the very first imagination it looks like

```
MyProject
|- /src            : uses dep2-client and implements effective dep1-client
|- /contrib
   *- /grpc
   |- /dep1-proto  : contains proto defs dep1
   |- /dep2-proto  : contains proto defs dep2
   |- /dep2-client : depends on dep2-proto
      *- /contrib/grpc
```

Unfortunately I found grpc the source code is not slim to be a library and you can see that I  has duplicated dependencies.

Sorry I cannot even give a deterministic question but just

"What is the best practice to handle this?"

Major troubles I encountered are

1. Overlap gRPC dependencies so that I don't know how to write CMakeLists.txt files properly in the root MyProject.
2. Meanwhile, I'd like to let dep1-proto, dep2-proto & dep2-client self-contained. I don't know what is the best practice such proto libraries should be built, shall we add gRPC as their dependency as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't necessarily install things system-wide. You can build gRPC with `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` set to your home directory, install it, and then point your project there to pick it up.

This is actually a preferred method, because downstream distribution packagers will be able to hook gRPC installed from their repo into your program.

Comment: The experience I'd like to have is something the same as how maven projects work, while gRPC could be a third-party gRPC instead of the official one as [how Apache Ratis(Incubating) did](https://github.com/apache/incubator-ratis-thirdparty). It seems C++ community doesn't have a central repository so I tend to do as the vendor way.